# NoMethodError: undefined method `categories' for #<Product:0x00000000070a9810>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to add categories for some products on Ruby on Rails, but I am getting an error saying *NoMethodError: undefined method `categories' for #*

Here is my product.rb :

```
 class Product < ApplicationRecord

  validates :title, presence: true

  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :categories, through :product_categories
 end
```

the product category app record:

```
class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

end
```

and the category.rb:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_categories
  has_many :products, through :product_categories
end
```

On the interactive ruby shell I give the following commands:

```
irb(main):006:0> Product.second!
Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" ORDER BY 
"products"."id" ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
=> #<Product id: 2, title: "bread", description: "with glutein", price: 
0.6e0, created_at: "2019-01-13 19:42:45", updated_at: "2019-01-13 
19:42:45">
irb(main):007:0> product= _
=> #<Product id: 2, title: "bread", description: "with glutein", price: 
0.6e0, created_at: "2019-01-13 19:42:45", updated_at: "2019-01-13 19:42:45">
irb(main):008:0> product = _

=> #<Product id: 2, title: "bread", description: "with glutein", price: 
0.6e0, created_at: "2019-01-13 19:42:45", updated_at: "2019-01-13 19:42:45">
<duct.categories.create!(title: "Bread")
NoMethodError: undefined method `categories' for
```

Could someone help me understand why this error appears? I am following this tutorial *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwoafJC7vlw* and it seems to work fine there.

Comment: I edited your post to fix a spelling in the code(`Product` model) & also an indentation(in `ProductCategory` model). Hope that wasn't the problem. You might wanna check.

Comment: Also, you are doing `duct.categories.create!` when you should be doing `product.categories.create!`

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari I think the `duct.categories.create!` is just a copy/paste error. In the title of the question, it says undefined method for product model.

Comment: @HalilC Yeah. Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Product` model please change `has_many :categories, through :product_categories` to `has_many :categories, through: :product_categories`. You need to add a colon after `through`. Same in `Category` model. This should solve the error.

In addition you have some other syntax errors / typos, for example in product model `validates` is written as `valitates`.